# ByteArrayOutputStream exception handling in java8

Tags: java, exception, io, bytearrayoutputstream, resource-leak

```
private void logSoapMessage(SOAPMessage soapMessage, String type) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = null;
        try {
            bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            soapMessage.writeTo(bout);
            logger.info("The " + type + " is " + bout.toString("UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.debug("Exception while logging soap message " + e);
        }
    }
```

**Is above code can give resource leak  error?**

Answer (score 5):

> Is above code can give resource leak error?

It isn't a resource leak.  Not in Java 8, or (AFAIK) in any other version.  (And it isn't a memory leak either.)

A `ByteArrayOutputStream` doesn't have any resources<sup>1</sup> that can leak.   Indeed, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close()) for `close()` on a `ByteArrayOutputStream` states that it has no effect.

**However**, an unsophisticated static checker *might* mistakenly flag your code as a *potential* resource leak.  You could either mark this as a "false positive" in the appropriate way, or just close the stream anyway.  The following is the best way to do the latter for Java 7 and later:

```
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        soapMessage.writeTo(bout);
        logger.info("The " + type + " is " + bout.toString("UTF-8"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.debug("Exception while logging soap message " + e);
    }
```

Note that the "leak" protection is not strictly necessary.  We are only doing this to stop the checker from giving us a false report.

---

<sup>1 - Resources refers to things such as *file descriptors* that are obtained from the operating system, and are often available in limited numbers.  If these resources are not managed properly by a Java application, there is a risk that the application will run out of them.  It is conventional for an object that holds a resource to implement `AutoClosable` and to provide a `close()` method to release the resource.  These objects often will use a finaliser or cleaner or similar to clean up leaked resources.  However, this may not be sufficient to prevent problems; e.g. depending on whether the GC identifies the objects as unreachable soon enough to trigger the clean up.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Its because you're not closing the resource when you're done with it.

Java 7 introduced the try-with-resource function:

```
private void logSoapMessage(SOAPMessage soapMessage, String type) {
  try (ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
    soapMessage.writeTo(bout);
    logger.info("The " + type + " is " + bout.toString("UTF-8"));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    logger.debug("Exception while logging soap message " + e);
  }
}
```

Which will automatically close the `ByteArrayOutputStream` even if it throws an exception.

The old way prior to java 7 you'd have to write it this way:

```
private void logSoapMessage(SOAPMessage soapMessage, String type) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bout = null;
  try {
    bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    soapMessage.writeTo(bout);
    logger.info("The " + type + " is " + bout.toString("UTF-8"));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    logger.debug("Exception while logging soap message " + e);
  } finally {
    if (bout != null) bout.close();
  }
}
```

To make sure the resource was closed prior to exiting the method and not get a resource leak.

Here is some info about the try-with-resource:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html